# jQuery DataTables display All Records as an option

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I'm using a purchased Admin theme for a web app that I'm building. That theme came with styles for jQuery dataTables. I'm trying to figure out how to add a View All Records option to the records per page drop down but because the theme came prestyled there is a lot of code already written and and I don't know how to add what I need to. Here is what I have:

Footer Code:

```
    <!-- jQuery DataTable -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        /* Default class modification */
        $.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
            "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
        } );

        /* API method to get paging information */
        $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function ( oSettings )
        {
            return {
                "iStart":         oSettings._iDisplayStart,
                "iEnd":           oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
                "iLength":        oSettings._iDisplayLength,
                "iTotal":         oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
                "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
                "iPage":          Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength ),
                "iTotalPages":    Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength )
            };
        }

        /* Bootstrap style pagination control */
        $.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination, {
            "bootstrap": {
                "fnInit": function( oSettings, nPaging, fnDraw ) {
                    var oLang = oSettings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
                    var fnClickHandler = function ( e ) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if ( oSettings.oApi._fnPageChange(oSettings, e.data.action) ) {
                            fnDraw( oSettings );
                        }
                    };

                    $(nPaging).addClass('pagination').append(
                        '<ul>'+
                            '<li class="prev btn-small disabled"><a href="#"><span class="awe-caret-left"></span> '+oLang.sPrevious+'</a></li>'+
                            '<li class="next btn-small disabled"><a href="#">'+oLang.sNext+' <span class="awe-caret-right"></span></a></li>'+
                        '</ul>'
                    );
                    var els = $('a', nPaging);
                    $(els[0]).bind( 'click.DT', { action: "previous" }, fnClickHandler );
                    $(els[1]).bind( 'click.DT', { action: "next" }, fnClickHandler );
                },

                "fnUpdate": function ( oSettings, fnDraw ) {
                    var iListLength = 0;
                    var oPaging = oSettings.oInstance.fnPagingInfo();
                    var an = oSettings.aanFeatures.p;
                    var i, j, sClass, iStart, iEnd, iHalf=Math.floor(iListLength/2);

                    if ( oPaging.iTotalPages < iListLength) {
                        iStart = 1;
                        iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
                    }
                    else if ( oPaging.iPage <= iHalf ) {
                        iStart = 1;
                        iEnd = iListLength;
                    } else if ( oPaging.iPage >= (oPaging.iTotalPages-iHalf) ) {
                        iStart = oPaging.iTotalPages - iListLength + 1;
                        iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
                    } else {
                        iStart = oPaging.iPage - iHalf + 1;
                        iEnd = iStart + iListLength - 1;
                    }

                    for ( i=0, iLen=an.length ; i<iLen ; i++ ) {

                        // Add / remove disabled classes from the static elements
                        if ( oPaging.iPage === 0 ) {
                            $('li:first', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                        } else {
                            $('li:first', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                        }

                        if ( oPaging.iPage === oPaging.iTotalPages-1 || oPaging.iTotalPages === 0 ) {
                            $('li:last', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                        } else {
                            $('li:last', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    </script>
```

What I want To Add (I Think, based off of another Stack Overflow question):

```
oTable = $('#example').dataTable({ "aLengthMenu": [
        [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
        [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
    ], 


"iDisplayLength" : -1 });
```

Comment: I was able to go into the actual dataTables.js file and make the change though that is obviously not the ideal way to go since I'd lose my change upon upgrading the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `oTable` is your dataTable instance, try:

```
var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
oSettings._iDisplayLength = 500;
oTable.fnDraw();
```

You can put this in an `onClick` too:

```
var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();

$('.changeLength').click(function(e){
   oSettings._iDisplayLength = 500;
   oTable.fnDraw(); 
});
```

That way when you click the button it changes the table length.